# PHP/MySQL retrieve posts and replies

Tags: php, mysql

The website I'm working currently at, is a php/mysql simple forum, for the purpose of learning programming.
So, I have 2 mysql tables (one in which I insert the main posts and another in which I insert the replies).
The structure is like this:

1. user1 date_posted
   message1
   -reply_button1-
2. user2 date_posted
   message2
   -reply_button2-

   3. user3 date_posted
      message3
      -reply_button3-
   4. user4 date_posted
      message4
      -reply_button4-
      etc...

MAIN FORM HERE THROUGH WHICH A USER CAN POST OTHER MAIN COMMENTS.

OBS When I say "main comments" I'm referring to posts like 1 and 2. The rest of them are replies to those main comments.

The problem is that when I want to put all the replies under their main comment (like fe, replies 3 and 4 should appear under the main comment 2), I don't know how to retrieve all those replies and display them correctly. I have some logic for this displaying, but the only issue is that it retrieves only some of them, but not all of them (fe, it grabs and displays only the first reply (with the id of 3) and not the second (with the id of 4).

I've searched on google for an idea, but failed to find something.

This is my code for retrieving replies: http://phprun.org/code/RKVMSYT-By-Guest

My tables: http://www.2shared.com/photo/-6kjm1vs/tables.html (you can see this picture without downloading it)
As it can be seen, the both ids from both table are not auto_increment fields. So the reply_id from forum_replies references one id from forum_comments if that reply is a reply for a main comment.

Any ideas on how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a where clause in your select.
Instead it appears that you pull the entire table, then iterate looking for responses.

Try using this:

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_replies WHERE reply_id =?");
$stmt2->execute(array($id));
```

This will give you a much faster return,  and you won't have to loop through every record, to see if you want it.

When I loop through a rowset,  this is my method...

```
foreach($stmt2 as $row) {

echo "this is id ".$row['id'];


}
```

Comment: A bad answer from you, unfortunately.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: I guess this website exists to get clear answers, and not to make some amends to other answers. But I think, sometimes, it is easely to touch the limit of the Universe than to get a proper answer. I'm saying this because there are so many created forums out there, but I can't find anything helpful to my problem.